# Using 2 different version of JNA in gradle

Tags: android, jna

So I realized that in JNA 4.3.0 and above, they remove a class called "WeakIdentityHashMap" and currently I'm using a third-party library that requires this class.

> I am not able to use the version 4.2.2 and below because I have another library that uses JNA 4.5.0 and above.

So is it possible to include both versions in the gradle?

I tried doing

```
dependencies 
{
implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.2.2'
implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.5.0'
}
```

in my build. gradle but it does not seem to work. I ended up only being able to use classes from 4.5.0. Any pieces of advice?